# AJAX - How to get data from input file to append formdata?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

Hello I want to use pure javascript ajax (no jquery) to append formdata but I don't know how to get data from  input file type

```
function handleForm(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('username', username); 
    data.append('email', email);
    data.append('file', ?????);  ////// How to get data from input file


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'test2.php', true);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);  
            alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');

        }
    }

    xhr.send(data);
}
```

...

```
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br/>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br/>
    Image: <input type="file" name="file" id="myimg"><br/>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your selector query  for `file`....

Comment: sorry  my selector for file is #myimg

Comment: So wouldn't it be a good idea to have a selector query for `myimg` just like you have with `username` and `email`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`<input type="file" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) HTML element has a [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) property (of type [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList)).
Check the length if a file has been selected and if so add the file(s) to the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myimg");
if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    data.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

For more examples on how to use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object check this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("file_input_id").files[0]
```

try

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to explain why the OP should use this and explain why it has `.file[0]` If you wish to post answers/solutions I would highly recommend giving detailed ones as some people wish to learn from the answers/solution given, not just copy/paste them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
```

to get file.. you can use

```
var myFile = $('#fileinput').prop('files')[0];
```

Comment: Um, this looks like jQuery to me... *"pure javascript ajax (no jquery)"*